# Why is the column invalid in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the price of the products that were ordered by more than 10 customers.
For that I use the Northwind sample database.

The relations between the required tables look like this:

```
[T]Orders       -> [K]CustomerID
                .. [K]OrderID

[T]OrderDetails -> [K]OrderID
                .. [K]ProductID
```

My solution as for now looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE Products
   SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 1.1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(o.CustomerID) NofCust
                 FROM Orders o
           INNER JOIN [Order Details] od
                   ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
                WHERE od.ProductID = ProductID
                      AND NofCust > 10
             GROUP BY od.ProductID);
```

I tried many different approaches, but there were problems with the select statement returning more than 1 row and so on, so this is the closest I got.

However the error I get in SQL Server is:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
Invalid column name 'NofCust'.
```

When I try a different approach which in theory shouldn't return more than 1 row:

```sql
UPDATE Products
   SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 1.1
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(o.CustomerID)
          FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] od
            ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
         WHERE od.ProductID = ProductID
      GROUP BY od.ProductID) > 10;
```

I get:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I assume that the second error may come from the fact that I can't name the table that I'm updating and can't explicitly say that I want, like:

```sql
ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
         WHERE od.ProductID = <ProductsToUpdate>.ProductID
      GROUP BY od.ProductID) > 10;
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: There is no column named `NofCust`, it's an alias which you can't use it in the same query. You may use `HAVING` there instead. For the second error, it's very clear.

Comment: @Sami thanks for the hint, that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to update the price of the products that were ordered by more than 10 customers.

I assume this means *distinct* customers.

For this, I think of a `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` more than `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE p
   SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 1.1
   FROM Products p JOIN
        (SELECT od.ProductId
         FROM Orders o JOIN
              [Order Details] od
              ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
         GROUP BY od.ProductId
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.CustomerId) > 10
        ) op
        ON op.ProductId = p.ProductId;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sami suggested the answer would be:

```sql
UPDATE Products
   SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 1.1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM Orders o
           INNER JOIN [Order Details] od
                   ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
                WHERE od.ProductID = ProductID
             GROUP BY od.ProductID
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.CustomerID) > 10);
```

WHERE clause cannot be used with an aggregate function, plus it's not possible to use an alias as a value.